# GitHub Actions API: Get view workflow run history

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I am looking for an API to retrieve previous runs of a specific workflow in GitHub Actions.
I found the API that returns the previous runs of my entire repository, but I only need the runs of a specific workflow.

This link perfectly describes what I am looking for as an API:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/viewing-workflow-run-history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/runs`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-workflow-runs) endpoint to list the runs of a given workflow ID in a given repository.

For example, to get all of the runs of the CI job for the `rust-lang/rust` repository, use [`https://api.github.com/repos/rust-lang/rust/actions/workflows/817415/runs`](https://api.github.com/repos/rust-lang/rust/actions/workflows/817415/runs).